# How to migrate table into schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I am trying to migrate a table (under db/migrate) that was automatically created with the model. When I run rake db:migrate, it is not updating my schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the schema actually look out of date? It may be that the schema has already been updated.

If it is out of date, try running:

```
rake db:migrate:reset
```

This will drop your DB, re-create your DB and then run all your migrations.

Comment: All fixed! Turns out it was always up to date.